# Eclipse 2022-06 gets error trying to install the Vaadin plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, vaadin8

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Vaadin Plug-in for Eclipse 4.1.6 (com.vaadin.integration.eclipse.feature.group 4.1.6)
Missing requirement: Vaadin Plug-in for Eclipse 4.1.6 (com.vaadin.integration.eclipse 4.1.6) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Vaadin Plug-in for Eclipse 4.1.6 (com.vaadin.integration.eclipse.feature.group 4.1.6)
To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.vaadin.integration.eclipse [4.1.6,4.1.6]

Comment: Does in the preferences _Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ adding the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest`](https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest) fix your issue?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: While adding, it is asking for name and location. What name should I add ? I guess location must be download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse 2022-06 does not contain Mylyn anymore which is required by the Vaadin plugin.

As solution, in the **preferences *Install/Update > Available Software Sites***, add the update site [**`https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest`**](https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest) before installing the Vaadin plugin.

**Update**:

Since Eclipse Eclipse 2023-06, Mylyn is back. So the following update site should work as well: [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/).

Comment: While adding, it is asking for name and location. What name should I add ? I guess location must be https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest/

Comment: Right. The name is just the label that is displayed in the settings. So you can choose whatever you want. By the way, [Eclipse Mylyn has moved to GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse-mylyn/) and there are new people working on getting it back into the simultaneous Eclipse IDE release.

Comment: Do we need to install all of the Maven parts, or just some as it lists:
Mylyn Features
Mylyn Integrations
Mylyn SDK and Framework
Mylyn Tests
Uncategorized

Comment: @YozonsOpeneSignForms Just add it to _Available Software Sites_ and everything required will be installed automatically while installing something.